# Print the smallest number in java

Tags: java

I need to take the user input and get the program to run it through all the methods and stuff to output the largest and smallest number.  I got it to print the largest, but it always has the smallest at 0.  This is probably simple to fix, but It's the end of the quarter and i'm stressing to get this last one done.  Here is my code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class P4_6
{
  private int sum;
  private int count;
  private int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  private int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

  public P4_6()
  {
    sum = 0;
    largest = 0;
    smallest = 0;
    count = 0;
  }
  public void addValue(int x)
  {
    smallest = Math.min(smallest, x);
    largest = Math.max(largest, x);
    sum = sum + x;
    count++;
  }

  public int getSum()
  {
    return sum;
  }

  public int getLargest()
  {

    return largest;
  }

  public int getSmallest()
  {
    return smallest;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner kbreader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your first integer: ");
    int num1 = kbreader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your second integer: ");
    int num2 = kbreader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your third integer: ");
    int num3 = kbreader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your fourth integer: ");
    int num4 = kbreader.nextInt();

    P4_6 data = new P4_6();
    data.addValue(num1);
    data.addValue(num2);
    data.addValue(num3);
    data.addValue(num4);

    System.out.println("The largest was " + data.getLargest());
    System.out.println("The smallest was " + data.getSmallest());

  }
}
```

Comment: `Math.min(0, x)` will return 0 for every positive `x`. Why are you resetting your fields in the constructor?

Comment: Yes, `largest` and `smallest` start with correct values, but then you set them to 0 in the constructor, which is wrong.  Looks like a type-o or went overboard with initializing the values.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use No-argument Constructor. Java compiler by default add No-argument Constructor . You can remove the below part.

```
public P4_6()
{
 sum = 0;
 largest = 0;
 smallest = 0;
 count = 0;
}
```

if you want to keep this part in your code then you should initialize your variable like below

```
public P4_6()
{
 sum = 0;
 largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
 smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
 count = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initialise the 'smallest' and 'largest'. Just remove them

```
public Test()
    {
        sum = 0;
        //largest = 0;
        //smallest = 0;
        count = 0;
    }
```